# Data from SQL reader to datatable - Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am keep trying and still don't know how to fix this, keep getting same error. I want to get data from the database to txt file.

```
    using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command)
    cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)conn;

    using (cmd)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        using(reader)
        {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                  dt.Load(reader);
             }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtPath.Text + fileName))
        {
            // write to text file from Datatable dt
        }  }
```

Comment: what is the error? couple things about the code should be done differently. the cmd should be defined on the using line, as should the reader, similar to you defined the sw variable. I don't see where dt is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try insted your code, something like this:

```
 DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();


        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(yourDBconn)
        {
                yourDBconn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strYourQuery, yourDBconn))
                {
                    myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Tested.

```
var customers = new List<Tuple<int, string>>(); // the list of ID, Name
using (var con = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID, Name from Customer", con))
    {
        con.Open();       
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                customers.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(
                    (int)reader["ID"], reader["Name"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
// Store customers to file
```